# Load JavaScript in only one webpage

Tags: javascript, window, href, indexof

I want a JavaScript to work only in one webpage of my forum, so I used this code:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/u1') != -1) {
```

But it also affects webpages like /u11, /u12, /u13, /u14, etc.

What can I do to make the code work only in /u1?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, I neglected the fact that your were using clean urls.

```
  //split url into an array separated by the /
  var url = window.location.href.split("/");

  //store the page that you want the script to execute on
  var rightPage = "u1";



//if the last index of the url array equals the value of the rightPage 
//note: -1 is subtracted because array indexes start at 0
if (url[url.length - 1] === rightPage) {//begin if then else


//do something if the your on the rightPage 
alert("right");

}
else{

//do something if you are not on rightPage
alert(page.join("/"));

}//end if then else
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work, the web page its just "u1" not "u1.html" take a look http://nootroheroemas.foroweb.org/u1

Answer (score 0):

This one finds out if there are an exact segment "u1" inside the url, but don't care of its position in the href path ( it would also return true for http://somewhere.com/one/two/three/u1/foo/bar ), but it is simple and should be enough.

```
var segments = window.location.href.split("/");
var found = false;
// You can also do this loop with index and count the position if needed
for (var segment in segments){
    if ( segment == "u1" ){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
// do with found whatever you need below
```